# How to get value and change url key's value by native javascript?

Tags: javascript, regex

I would like to make a caching mechanism. I want to drop the last digit of the latitude and longitude for example :

look below how to make request. important things are the "lat" and "lon" values.  There must be four digits after the full stop (also known as a period).

```
3 Request /v1/x/y/?lat=40.12225&lon=2.13422&radius=1&key=abc
caching look up: /v1/x/y/?lat=40.1222&lon=2.1342&radius=1&key=abc-> no match (look at lat=40.1222&lon=2.1342)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the following regex to trim your strings to the correct format:

`/(?:lat|lon)(=\d+\.\d{4})\d*/g` then you replace with `$1`

Example:

```
var s = "/v1/x/y/?lat=40.12323&lon=2.13421&radius=1&key=abc"
s.replace(/((?:lat|lon)=\d+\.\d{4})\d*/g,"$1");

Output:
/v1/x/y/?lat=40.1232&lon=2.1342&radius=1&key=abc
```